# Add Association Class to Composition relationship

Tags: uml

I'd like to know if it is correct to add an Association Class to a Composition relationship?

For example (see figure below), can I add an Association Class (i.e. *NameValue* class) to the composition relationship between *Name* class and *Value* class? One *Name* can have multiple *Value* and one *Value* can only be attached to one *Name*. *NameValue* class stores the name-value pairs.

The reason why I create the association class (i.e. *NameValue* class) is that I need to create associations/relationships between *NameValue* class and other classes such as *Class A*.

If the answer is yes, is it recommended to turn the association class into a normal class?

[image]

Many thanks!

Comment: it seems this is the night (my time) of the association-class :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like to know if it is correct to add an Association Class to a Composition relationship?

yes in an association-class the association can have an owner-end property being a composition, in [formal/2017-12-05](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1) there is nothing in § *11.5.3.2 Association Classes* starting page 200 nor in § *11.8.2 AssociationClass [Class]* against that even association-class has some constraints

> NameValue class stores the name-value pairs.

note this is absolutely not the goal of the class of an association-class in UML, and not necessary the case when you implement an association-class

> The reason why I create the association class (i.e. NameValue class) is that I need to create associations/relationships between NameValue class and other classes such as Class A

because *NameValue* is used at implementation level to stores the name-value pairs and then to implement the association(-class), in UML the diagram you want is :

[image]

(*NameValue* does not exist at UML level but only at implementation level)

> If the answer is yes, is it recommended to turn the association class into a normal class?

At UML level the association-class do not exist for nothing, they make the model clear, so I do not recommend to not use class-association (but this is of course opinion-based)

Comment: Hi bruno, thanks for you reply. The NameValue association class is actually a significant class in my uml diagram as it has relationships with quite a number of classes, so I was wondering if it is fine to create the NameValue association class for this purpose so that  how the NameValue class is related to other classes can be presented in a clearer way?

Comment: @snow difficult to answer without knowing more the other uses of *NameValue*. Anyway let me say just by its name *NameValue* just associating *name* and *value* so being 'poor' / having a 'low level' of meaning, the class is questionable. Generally when we are not able to find a 'good' name for an element this is because that element is not a good solution.

Comment: that makes sense. Sorry for not explaining the details of NameValue class. It is actually a class called Property which associates PropertyName (example of instance: Level) and PropertyValue (example of instances: High, Medium, Low). The Property class also contains an ID field. The Property class has association with other classes such as User (which means User has Property), Resource (which means Resource has Property), etc.

Comment: Just to add one more point, the Property association class has own constraints as well.

Comment: @snow One thing is sure : at UML level the class used to make an association_class does not at all store the pairs of instances of the classes linked by the association, that is the role of the properties (owner ends) of the association. If you have an association-class rather than only an association this is because you need to add the semantic of the class to your association.

Comment: @snow  A typical example is the association-class between a company and an employee, where the class manages the employment contract and salary and hiring date etc. All of that concern the pair company and employee and not only the company or the employee, and a company can have several employee and an employee can be in several company at the same time or sequentially. If you are in that kind of case the association-class has sense

Comment: Hi bruno, I've got your point, many thanks!